# Spectral bands on an Earth-observing satellite

Tags: artificial-satellite, image-processing

What does it mean when a satellite has these bands[1]:

- Panchromatic: 450-800 nm
- 8 Multispectral (red, red edge, coastal, blue, green, yellow, near-IR1 and near-IR2): 400 nm-1,040 nm
- 8 SWIR: 1,195 nm-2,365 nm
- 12 CAVIS Bands (desert clouds, aerosol-1, aerosol-2, aerosol-3, green, water-1, water- 2, water-3, NDVI-SWIR, cirrus, snow): 405 nm - 2,245 nm

Does it have 4 bands or does it have 29 bands? What does a band physically look like?

[1] https://www.satimagingcorp.com/satellite-sensors/worldview-3/

Comment: See also [EarthScience.SE] where Earth Observation questions may be on-topic.

Comment: The [excellent, clear, accepted answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29555/12102) demonstrates that this question is *neither* "too broad" nor "unclear". The current close votes for those reasons seem unjustified.

Comment: without commenting on this question, just because someone guessed what the asker meant doesn't mean the question wasn't unclear, @uhoh, just because the answer satisfied the asker doesn't mean it covered the question in the breadth it needed to be done justice.

Comment: @JCRM "could be worded better" can be addressed by editing or by helpful comments rather than the silent insta-close. In low question-rate sites like this, I think that the "close early, close often" attitude is unnecessary, and unnecessarily discouraging to new users. See [Be welcoming - a new Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/988/12102) for example. In the case of this question though, I think the intent of the question is really quite clear, and there's nothing "too broad" about it whatsoever.

Comment: @JCRM With two close votes in the first five hours already, and the occasional reflexive close-voters piling on, the question might end up closed and then take time to reopen, thereby preventing other people from posting answers in the mean time. The reason I leave counter-arguments to the silent close votes is to give potential reflexive close-voters an opportunity to pause and see that other people do understand the question.

Comment: @uhoh, indeed, could be worded better could be addressed by editing, but if one can't work out what the question is asking one can't improve it; if a question  is too broad one could attempt a partial answer, but at the risk of not answering the question the asker meant. Too many poor quality questions are discouraging.Telling people they are wrong for not following uhoh's flawed logic would do is counter productive - it makes me want to close vote the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'bands' described here are regions of the [electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum). A band doesn't *physically* look like anything since it's just a range of wavelengths. However, different wavelengths are good for imaging different physical phenomena.

So WorldView-3 has sensors for 4 *groups* of bands, but 29 bands in total.

The page you linked includes [this image](https://content.satimagingcorp.com/static/galleryimages/worldview-3-spectral-bands.jpg) which illustrates the bands in which WorldView-3's sensors operate:

[image]

Comment: A band might look like a filter, if filters are used to implement spectral bands.  In visible wavelengths, that will look like a (possibly coloured) piece of translucent glass.

Comment: Great answer! I've just asked [How (the heck) does a spacecraft manage 29 different spectral bands? One giant filter wheel, or…?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29562/12102)